# How to stop auto update and see how much space each update would take?

Tags: updates, disk-usage

I'm using school internet and we're not allowed to download large amount of data (>800mb). How do I stop auto update and see how much space each update will take up? (Before installation, I mean).

Comment: Information about your OS would be helpful. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: If you open the terminal and update that way, you will see how much data it takes and then, answer Y(yes) or N(no) to accept or reject the upgrades

Comment: You can google how to use the terminal, very simple actually.  Plus you'll be proud of yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the terminal and update that way, you will see how much data it takes and then, answer Y(yes) or N(no) to accept or reject the upgrades.

You can google how to use the terminal, very simple actually. Plus you'll be proud of yourself!